How can I add fields for capturing trade data in Murex?
I am looking for a way to add and store two new fields to be manually filled in by the people responsible for tracking transactions. Since we recently migrated to this system, I’m not sure which type of user profile has the permissions to modify the trade details form.
I'm referring to the form that can be accessed from a Back Office profile under 'Processing/Trades/Trade Query'.
